# In Ionic 2 Integrated AutocompleteService() but not working.It's Show message like while running

Tags: autocomplete, ionic2

[image]

In this line of code i am getting error as shown below.
//autocomplete.ts

```
import {Component, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
import {ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';
declare var google:any;

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete.html'
})

export class AutocompletePage {
  autocompleteItems;
  autocomplete;
  service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

  constructor (public viewCtrl: ViewController, private zone: NgZone) {
    this.autocompleteItems = [];
    this.autocomplete = {
      query: ''
    };
  }

  dismiss() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }

  chooseItem(item: any) {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(item);
  }

  updateSearch() {
    if (this.autocomplete.query == '') {
      this.autocompleteItems = [];
      return;
    }
    let me = this;
    this.service.getPlacePredictions({ input: this.autocomplete.query, componentRestrictions: {country: 'IN'} }, function (predictions, status) {
      me.autocompleteItems = []; 
      me.zone.run(function () {
        predictions.forEach(function (prediction) {
          me.autocompleteItems.push(prediction.description);
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Above is the code which i written in file to get autocompleteservice from google Api
Above Attach photo having the error which got at run time.

Getting Error here.

```
service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
```

i Don't know why it's happining.
Thank you.

Comment: you need to provide relevant code by editing your question..[mcve]

Comment: add the component where you are setting this otherwise no one can tell.

Comment: you havent declared `google`.. `declare var google:any` immediately after imports and before the class

Comment: still having the same error.I already tried that but not working. @suraj, Know i Edited my code as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I get the solution of my question by changing the script in index.html in ionic 2:

// First i have this below script and just remove `&callback=initMap` from your api or copy paste the second script i had written below:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

Replace by this :

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```